# text restyling in python

Tags: python, perl

i have a text file which has thousands of lines something like this format (a, b, c, d, e) (here, a is 6 digited number, b is 3 letter code, c is date, d is floating number and e is -1, 0 or 1) i want to restyle it in this format (b, c, d). 
e.g. (345678, 'ABC', '2010-01-01', 0.123, '-1') => ('ABC', '2010-01-01', 0.123)

i just dont know where to start? 
in python if i assigned the line to a variable, then what have to be done? split or something else?

i have some knowledge on perl too, so any help in any of these twlo langs will be appreciated -))

```
text = open('text.txt', 'w')

for line in text:
    #
    # 
    #
```

Comment: why is `perl` tag included when subject says python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split lines by `,\s()` char class, take values from 2,3,4 positions, and put `()` around them.

```
perl -F'[,\s\(\)]+' -ape '$_ = join ", ", @F[2,3,4]; $_ = "($_)"' text.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
import ast
with open("in.txt") as infile, open("out.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        contents = ast.literal_eval(line)
        outfile.write(str(contents[1:4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need something along these lines :-

```
for line in text:
    line = line.strip('()')
    fields = line.split(',')
    print "(%s,%s,%s)" % (fields[1], fields[2], fields[3])
```

You may want to consider sed or awk for one liners that do the same if you are on a unix like system.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in text
    s = line.split(',')
    print("({0},{1},{2})".format(s[1], s[2], s[3]))
```